# Angular issue : how to update form using ng-model="userObject.id" using post

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm trying to update form using Angular js framework, and the ngmodel name is separated by dot 
eg:- `ng-model="userObject.id".`

how will i post userObject.id in php. check with below syntax

eg:- `$categoryid = $request->categoryid;`

how would i will post `userObject.id` in above syntax

is this right way to write code  `$categoryid = $request->userObject.id;`?

but when i write code `$categoryid = $request->userObject.id; browser come with an error.

```js
//controll

$scope.data = {};
    $scope.update = function() {
        var link = 'webServices/updateCategory.php';
        $http.post(link, { category_name: $scope.data.category_name, order_no: $scope.data.order_no }).then(function(res) {
            $scope.response = res.data;
            //  alert("Records updated successfully...");
            //$window.location.reload();
        });
    };
```

```html
html code

<form class="form-horizontal">
                        <input type="hidden" ng-model="userObject.id">
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                            <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="test" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" ng-model="userObject.category_name" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                            <label for="age" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Age</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="test" class="form-control" id="age" placeholder="Age" ng-model="userObject.order_no" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" ng-model="$scope.objectIndex" class="ng-valid">
                        <div class="btn-group col-sm-2">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn" ng-click="update();"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></i>Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>




<?
//php code
include("../include/connection.php");

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
 if (isset($postdata)) {
  $request = json_decode($postdata);
        $id = $request->userObject.id;
        echo $id;
  $category_name = $request->userObject.category_name;
        echo $category_name;
        $order_no = '5';
            mysqli_query($con, "update category set `category_name`='".$category_name."', `order_no`='".$order_no."' where id='".$id."'");
   echo "Your account is created successfully";
 }
 else {
  echo "Not called properly with username parameter!";
 }
?>
```

thank you`

Comment: Please add the output of `print_r($request)` to your question.

Comment: @nvisser output is stdClass Object ( )

Comment: @nvisser how will access stdClass Object ( ) ?

Comment: That indicates that you're not sending any data from Angular. Be sure to double check that Angular is sending the right data.

Comment: @nvisser  i'm sending data using ng-model please check with below code
`<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" ng-model="userObject.category_name" />`

Comment: @nvisser hey dude can you please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$request->{'userObject.id'}` to access that variable.

[Source](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

Comment: i copied above and it is
showing notice : on this line  `$id = $request->{'userObject.id'};`
  Undefined property: ` stdClass::$userObject.id `